# Como criar um campo nas coordenadas do EventClick do FullCalendar

Tags: php, javascript

[image: Gostaria de editar essa linha]

Como criar um campo editável nas coordenadas do eventclick

[JS]

```
$('#calendariousuariodia').fullCalendar({
        header: {                   
            right: 'month,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        allDay: true,
        selectable: true,       
        nowIndicator: true,
        events:         
                {
                url: 'estrutura/agendauser.php',                
                error: function() {
                    console.log('Não existem eventos para exibir!');
                } 
                },  
        eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
            $el.popover({
            title: eventObj.title,
            content: eventObj.description,
            trigger: 'hover',
            placement: 'top',
            container: 'body'
            });
        },
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {  

            var cbmdoutor = document.getElementById('cbmdoutor').value  

            if(cbmdoutor == ""){
                toastr["error"]('Favor selecionar um Cirurgião');
                $("#cbmdoutor").focus();
                exit;   
            } else {

                $('#txttitulo').show();
                $('#txtdesc').show();
                $("#txttitulo").focus();

                $("#dtstart").val(moment(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
                $("#dtend").val(moment(end).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
                $("#hrstart").val(moment(start).format('HH:mm'));
                $("#hrend").val(moment(end).format('HH:mm'));
            }

        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

            alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
            alert('data: ' + calEvent.id);
            alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
            alert('View: ' + view.name);

            // Ja tenho as coordenadas
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

          }


    });
```

Comment: Eu tb pergunto: como vc vai editar isso?

Comment: Jefferson, se você ler da documentação vai ver que o evento `eventClick` te passa como parâmetros as coordenadas do evento que foi clicado, daí você pode colocar um campo editável "em cima" do evento e depois salvar, veja aqui: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

Comment: Como faço para abrir esse campo? não achei um exemplo, pois os eventos eu consigui, tanto com eventclick como o select.